# Google Fusion Table to Google Spreadsheet - Update Spreadsheet by selected criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables, google-sheets-api

I am a beginner in coding and I am running a script to update a Google Spreadsheet with data from a Google Fusion Table. The data of the Fusion Table contains round about 100 different columns.

I want to evaluate only selected columns, for example: Date, FirstName, LastName, Department. The searching criteria looks like:

Update on the Spreadsheet the following columns "Date, FirstName, LastName, Department where Department contains HR".

I am using the following script:

```
function runQuery() {
var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department WHERE Department contains HR' + 'TableID';
var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
hdrs: false
});
if (result.rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

     sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
    .setValues(result.rows);
  }
}
```

It is no problem to select Columns and transfer the data from the Fusion Table to the Spreadsheet. The following error occurs, when I want to show only data with the above mentioned selection critera ("where Department contains HR"):

-Invalid query: Parse error near 'WHERE' (line 1, position 33). (Zeile 3, Datei "runQuery")-

It would be great, if someone can help me. Thank you in advanced.

### Jens

UPDATE "Jens"!

This function works fine. Ther I receive selected data by the following criterias.

```
var tableName = '1sJjfOJ4Q.....'

function runQuery() {

var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department, EMail from ' + 'tableName';

var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
hdrs: false
});
if (result.rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();


// Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
      .setValues(result.rows);
 }
}
```

when I add the "where clause" an errors occures:

```
var tableName = '1sJjfOJ4Q.....'    

function runQuery() {
var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department, EMail from ' + 'tableName' + 'WHERE Department contains HR';

var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
hdrs: false
});
if (result.rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();


// Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
      .setValues(result.rows);
 }
}
```

The error look like this:
Invalid query: Parse error near 'Department' (line 1, position 101). Invalid table id 1sJjfOJ4...-xLfYohPizswhere (line 7, file "Code")"

It seems, the "var result " in line 7 is not correct and I don`t know why.

---

Update "Rod"!

```
var tableName = '1sJjfOJ4Q.....'    

function runQuery() {
var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department, EMail from ' + 'tableName' + "WHERE Department contains 'HR'";

var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
hdrs: false
});
if (result.rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();


// Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
      .setValues(result.rows);
 }
}
```

The same error occures (see Update ME)--> It seems, the "var result " in line 7 is not correct and I don`t know why.

---

Update "Henrique"!

```
function runQuery() {
var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department, EMail from 1sJjfOJ4Q..... WHERE Department contains HR';

var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
hdrs: false
});
if (result.rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();


// Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
      .setValues(result.rows);
 }
}
```

The following error occures: 
Invalid query: Parse error near 'HR' (line 1, position 120). (line 7, file "Code")
It seems, the "var result " in line 7 is not correct and I don`t know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your select needs a `FROM` before the `WHERE`. There should be a space between the `tableID` and the `WHERE` clause. Lastly, the string "HR" should be wrapped in quotes. Try this:

`sql = "SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department FROM "+tableID+" WHERE Department contains 'HR'";`

Assuming you have a `tableID` variable set with the correct value before you call this function.

Comment: Hi, Henrique. Thanks for your reply. In your case (+TableID+) I guess the table id will not be "activated". I tried another version, but also her an error occures:   "var sql = 'SELECT Date, FirstName, LastName, Department FROM ' + '18IA-fm....._' + 'WHERE Department contains HR';" The error is called: "Invalid query: Parse error near 'Department' (line 1, position 101). Invalid table id 1sJjfOJ4....WHERE (Zeile 5, Datei "runQuery")". --> The table ID is valid. I am working on the same spreadsheet with this tableID. Hm... Maybe you have also a other solution.... BR Jens

Comment: The argument for "contains" has to be enclosed in single quotes. Easiest way would be to enclose the where clause in double quotes: "where Department contains 'HR'"

Comment: @Jens it seems you forgot to add a space between the tableID and the WHERE clause. If you're going to hard-code it (which seems is what you're doing, then remove the quotes and pluses, e.g. `... Department FROM 18Ia-fmbla WHERE etc...`

Comment: @Rod, pls. see updated code above (Update "Rod"!). An error occures. And I guess, there is an mistake in the "var result". I tried to figure it out, but I don`t know where the issue is. Do you see the issue?

Comment: @Henrique here it is the same Issue, as I mentioned to Rod. Pls. see the "Update Henrique!" above. I cannot find the issue at all. Maybe some one of you has another idea... Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Jens I edited my answer to include this "HR" issue. Note that to wrap it in single quotes I changed the string delimiter to double quotes.

Comment: @Henrique. It is not working. I checked it out and tried variations on coding... Are you working with your coding solution? THX Jens

Comment: I wrote the quotes around `tableID` wrong, it's fixed now. And I tested the code. It works.